How to implement browser tab visibility in gwt
Motivation: I have a periodic call to server to supply fresh data to user. But my program can be run in multiply tabs. I want to decrease the load on the server by detecting which tab is active. If I can reach the state direcly or put the state of visibility of the tab to a variable, my periodic code can check that variable and decide not to call server.
Javascript code: I have found relevant code on javascipt at here
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {
  var tabIsVisible = !document.hidden;
  console.log("tabIsVisible: " + tabIsVisible);   
});

In GWT I can rewrite the code as this
public static native void addEventListener_visibilityChange(){
    $doc.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {
      var tabIsVisible = !document.hidden;
      console.log("tabIsVisible: " + tabIsVisible);
    });
}

But it gives compile error
Compiling module com.tugalsan.app.table.App
   Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.tugalsan.api.gui.client.browser.TGC_BrowserTabUtils'
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/tugalsan/com.tugalsan.api.gui/1.0-SNAPSHOT/com.tugalsan.api.gui-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/tugalsan/api/gui/client/browser/TGC_BrowserTabUtils.java'
         [ERROR] Line 8: syntax error
>         $doc.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {

And, how can I even reach the tabIsVisible variable?

The => arrow syntax is not supported in JSNI. That said, JSNI is discouraged for the last 10 or so years, prefer JsInterop instead.
Javascript event handling like this translates pretty easily to JsInterop with Java 8+ syntax. I'm also going to assume you have elemental2-dom in your project, a set of bindings to DOM apis that the browser provides. With one import for elemental2.dom.DomGlobal we can now write
DomGlobal.document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", event -> {
  // most coding styles prefer boolean over var:
  var tabIsVisible = !DomGlobal.document.hidden;
  DomGlobal.console.log("tabIsVisible: " + tabIsVisible);   
});

The only differences are:

The DomGlobal. prefix for document and console - technically these are optional, since you could add static imports for those two fields, but many company code standards discourage that.
The => JS token needs to be changed to Java's ->.
The event parameter for the lambda but be explicitly declared, even though it isn't used.

Technically you can keep var and not use boolean, but many coding styles prefer being more specific in simple cases like this. I like to stick with var for the first pass of translating from JS to Java, but will usually replace with types before committing any code.

Than you again... As there is no migration tutorial available, I don't know where to begin with. But I will try to migrate elemental2 slowly. I wish there is a project to convert source code gwt to source code elemental2. So people can learn elemental2 with their own code.

Migration isn't mandatory, GWT isn't removing JSNI (though you can't use JSNI if you switch to J2CL). Elemental2 just exposes the browsers' own APIs, use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ or other similar resources to understand what those APIs do, and following the simple rules above and looking briefly at the generated code in Elemental2 you should be able to see how to handle 90% of cases right away.
